# Get all options from select via POST

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I am building a page in which I have 2 select boxes. I add items to Select #2 from Select #1.

When the submit button is clicked, I want to get all options only from Select #2 whether they are selected or not.

```
<?php
require('handlers/handler.php');
$active = $_POST['activeProperties'];
$slider = $_POST['sliderProperties'];
$array = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['sliderProperties'])){
        foreach($_POST['sliderProperties'] as $item){
            $array[] = $item;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>

<form method="post" style="height: 600px;">
            <select id="source" name="activeProperties[]" data-text="Source list" data-search="Search for options" style="height: 600px;">
                <?php 
                $query = $handler11->query("SELECT ID, name FROM properties WHERE active = 'yes' ");
                while($row = $query->fetch()){
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select id="destination" name="sliderProperties[]" data-text="Destination list"  data-search="Search for options">
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
    </form>
```

I am only getting the first item in the select box with this code. How can I get all items?

Comment: You are not selecting `feld1` in your db or you need to use  `$row['name']` depends on which one is true

Comment: that was a typo sorry...the first select is being populated from database. How can i get all options from destination select whether they are selected or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the multiple select of HTML (documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple)), try this:

```
<form method="post" style="height: 600px;">
    <select multiple id="source" name="activeProperties[]" data-text="Source list" data-search="Search for options" style="height: 600px;">
        <?php 
            $query = $handler11->query("SELECT ID, name FROM properties WHERE active = 'yes' ");
            while($row = $query->fetch()){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

the other option is doing through Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the data if selected or not, cant you get the same result in your php by this query :

`$query = $handler11->query("SELECT ID, name FROM properties WHERE active = 'yes'` "`);`

Comment: all the data i pass to the destinations select